# Probability bound on sum of geometric random variables

Tags: probability, large-deviation-theory

Suppose each $X_i$ is a geometric distribution with probability $p = 1/2$. That is $X_i$ measures the number of coin flips it takes until you get a heads. Let $X = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$. Clearly $E[X] = 2n$. Is there a good way to bound, say, $P(X > 10 n)$? I think it should be exponentially unlikely in $n$ but can't figure out how to prove that.

Comment: This is just probability sample mean deviates from population mean by more than $8$. The easiest bound is just to use sub exponential tail bound

Comment: e.g. section 5.1.2 here: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36709/S19/Scribed_Lectures/Feb5_Aleksandr.pdf

Comment: Sorry I don't follow your logic. I don't see why it's the same as that.

Comment: $P(X>10n) = P(X/n-2>8)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(e^{sX_1})=\frac{e^s}{2-e^s}$ for $s<\log 2.$ Thus for $0<s<\log 2$ and Markov inequality $\Pr(Y>y)\leq \frac{1}{y}E(Y)$ we have

$$\Pr(X>10n)=\Pr(e^{sX}>e^{s10n})\leq e^{-s10n}\left(\frac{e^s}{2-e^s}\right)^n$$ The minimum is obtained by choosing $s=19/10$ and you get the following majorization
$$\Pr(X>10n)\leq\left(\frac{10^{10}}{19^9}\right)^n.$$

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Isn't e^s/(2-e^s)  negative at s = 19/10?

Comment: oh sorry, I mean $e^s=19/10.$ Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If your geometric random variables are independent then I believe this note should be useful, the main theorem on page 3 looks to be such a bound:
[https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~browndg/negbin.pdf](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebrowndg/negbin.pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).